# Add class to ember link-to

Tags: ember.js

I try to build a link to a nested route and want to add a class to this link (for twitter bootstrap)

The result should something like this:

```
< a href="/#/rents/42" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">do something< /a>
```

First try:

```
{{#link-to "rent" rent}}
```

gives me a link to the ressource but I cannot specify a (css) class. In the docs I see that only the title attribute can be specified

Second try:

```
< a href="/#/rents/{{rend.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">do something< /a>
```

is also a bad idea, because Ember will add its helper tags [for automatic updates] in the href.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use:

`{{#link-to 'rent' rent class='btn btn-primary btn-small'}}Go to rent{{/link-to}}`

As `link-to` is a view helper.

Comment: **awesome**! I didn't knew I could add view attributes to the helpers.

Comment: This does not work in version 1.13.7 of ember anymore as it fails to add the `ember-view` class, without wich it will just be a normal link and reload the page.  Using just `class="btn btn-primary etc"` as proposed in Connors answer below works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 10):

You can add classes just fine in `{{#linkTo}}` helpers, you just need to remember not to confuse ember.

Ember may think your class is the `routeName` of the `params`, I include the class after both `params` and `routeName` and it works fine.

```
{{#linkTo 'dashboard.screenshots' value.model class='thumbnail'}}
   ........
{{/linkTo}}
```

Produces

```
<a id="ember507" class="ember-view thumbnail" href="#/project-2/member-1/task-2/screenshot-30">
   .........
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want manually construct something from variables - there is `{{unbound}}` helper in ember.js.

In yor case code will looks like:

```
<a href="/#/rents/{{unbound rend.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">
   do something
</a>
```

Comment: You should be using {{#link-to}} helper.