# ember: How can I set bind-attr for a link-to?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emblem.js

I want to set the style of a link-to helper but don't quite understand how.

I have the following model:

```
App.ArtistFavorite = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  image_url: DS.attr 'string'
```

My template:

```
li
  link-to 'artistFavorite' this {bind-attr style="background-image: url('image-url');"}
```

But the bind-attr doesn't seem to work

BTW: I'm using emblemjs and coffeescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link-to` is an Ember view helper, so (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552911/build-a-link-with-a-specific-class-in-ember-js-using-handlebars)) I was originally going to suggest [using `attributeBindings`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_html-attributes), except that raises the following JS error:

> Setting 'attributeBindings' via Handlebars is not allowed. Please subclass Ember.View and set it there instead.

It looks like if you really need to set attributes in this way, it is possible to do so by [reopening](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_link-to) the `Ember.LinkView` class and setting `attributeBindings` there, but be forewarned that this will affect every `link-to` on your page.

But if (as it appears) the only attribute you need to set is `style`, you can just create a CSS class with your desired style and then set `classNames`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552911/build-a-link-with-a-specific-class-in-ember-js-using-handlebars), i.e.:

```
{{#link-to 'artistFavorite' this classNames="your-class-name"}}
```

From a code-style perspective, I would go with this approach even if it was possible to (more easily) set the `style` attribute directly.

---

**Edit**: *Just* realized you are trying to individually set styles for each link using one of the attributes of the corresponding item, so obviously CSS classes would not work. I've thought about this a bit more though.

Although discouraged, you should be able to bind to the `style` attribute by reopening the `LinkView` class and adding `style` to the `attributeBindings`:

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ["style"]
})
```

Then *possibly* you could set a value for the `style` attribute:

```
{{#link-to 'artistFavorite' this style=favStyle}}
```

Where `favStyle` is a computed property on your model or (ideally) your controller:

```
favStyle: function() {
  return "background-image: url('" + this.get('image_url') + "');";
}.property('image_url')
```

However I haven't tested this and I'm not 100% certain the binding will work correctly this way, because these bindings are typically used for plain-text, not properties.